# PHP script generating a double mySQLI query

Tags: php

This is my code.

I'm developing a form that is supposed to insert all the data into a database, and at the same time, print it on a PDF file.

I mean, it does work.
I've generated some pretty neat documents using it, but I have a problem.
When I press the "save" button, it will make a *double query* and will add everything *twice* into the database. What am I doing wrong here?
I'd appreciate if you guys have any pointers here.

I'm using a local server as a test with phpMyAdmin.

```
    <?php
      require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
      $con = mysqli_connect("hosthere", "databasehere", "passwordhere", "banco");
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Error while connecting to the database" . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
          $relacion   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["relacion"]);
          $r_otra     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["otro"]);
          $a1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["apellido"]);
          $a2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["apellido2"]);
          $n          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Nombres"]);
          $tid        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["tipoid"]);
          $otraid        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["otraid"]);
          $nid        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["numeroid"]);
          $did        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["detallesid"]);
          $bdate      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["fechanac"]);
          $bplace     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["lugarnac"]);
          $ecivil     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["estadocivil"]);
          $conyugue   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["conyugue"]);
          $sex        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["sexo"]);
          $country    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["pais"]);
          $country2   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["pais2"]);
          $carrera    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["profesion"]);
          $d1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["direccion1"]);
          $d2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["direccion2"]);
          $m1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["municipio1"]);
          $m2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["municipio2"]);
          $dp1        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["depto1"]);
          $dp2        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["depto2"]);
          $p1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["pais1"]);
          $p2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["pais2"]);
          $cel        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cel1"]);
          $t1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["tel1"]);
          $t2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["tel2"]);
          $c1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cel1"]);
          $f1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["fax1"]);
          $f2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["fax2"]);
          $e1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email1"]);
          $e2         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email2"]);
          $area       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["area"]);
          $cargo      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cargo"]);
          $antiguedad = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["antiguedad"]);
          $status     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["estatus"]);
          $emp        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["empresa"]);
          $denomsoc   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["denomsoc"]);
          $nombrecomercial     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["nombrecomercial"]);
          $rtnruc         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["rtnruc"]);
          $d3         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["d3"]);
          $m3          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["m3"]);
          $dp3        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["dp3"]);
          $p3        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["p3"]);
          $t3        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["t3"]);
          $www      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["www"]);
          $tipoemp     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["tipoemp"]);
          $otroemp     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["otroemp"]);
          $actecon     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["actecon"]);
          $otraact   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["otraact"]);
          $time=strtotime($bdate);
          $month=date("m",$time);
          $year=date("y",$time);
          $day=date("d",$time);
          $male="";
          $female="";
            if ($sex=="1"){
              $male="X";
            } else{
              $female="X";
            }
          $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (relacion, otro, Nombres, Apellido1, Apellido2, tipo_id, otra_id, numero_id, detalles_id, fecha_nacimiento, lugar_nacimiento, estado_civil, conyugue, sexo, nacionalidad, profesion, direccion1, municipio1, departamento1, pais1, telefono1, celular, email1, estatus, empresa, area, cargo, antiguedad, direccion2, municipio2, departamento2, pais2, telefono2, fax1, email2, denomsoc, nombrecomercial, rtnruc, d3, m3, dp3, p3, t3, www, tipoemp, otroemp, actecon, otraact) VALUES ('$relacion', '$r_otra', '$n', '$a1', '$a2', '$tid', '$otraid', '$nid', '$did', '$bdate', '$bplace', '$ecivil', '$conyugue', '$sex', '$country', '$carrera', '$d1', '$m1', '$dp1', '$pais1', '$t1', '$cel', '$e1', '$status', '$emp', '$area', '$cargo', '$antiguedad', '$d2', '$m2', '$dp2', '$country2', '$t2', '$f1', '$e2', '$denomsoc', '$nombrecomercial', '$rtnruc', '$d3', '$m3', '$dp3', '$p3', '$t3', '$www', '$tipoemp', '$otroemp', '$actecon', '$otraact')";
      if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      } else {
      // long procedure to print everything using DOMPDF.
      }
?>
```

This is the printing procedure:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  } else {
      if ($_POST) {
          $relacion   = $_REQUEST["relacion"];
          $r_otra     = $_REQUEST["otro"];
          $a1         = $_REQUEST["apellido"];
          $a2         = $_REQUEST["apellido2"];
          $n          = $_REQUEST["Nombres"];
          $tid        = $_REQUEST["tipoid"];
          $otraid     = $_REQUEST["otraid"];
          $nid        = $_REQUEST["numeroid"];
          $did        = $_REQUEST["detallesid"];
          $bplace     = $_REQUEST["lugarnac"];
          $ecivil     = $_REQUEST["estadocivil"];
          $conyugue   = $_REQUEST["conyugue"];
          $sex        = $_REQUEST["sexo"];
          $country    = $_REQUEST["pais"];
          $carrera    = $_REQUEST["profesion"];
          $d1         = $_REQUEST["direccion1"];
          $d2         = $_REQUEST["direccion2"];
          $m1         = $_REQUEST["municipio1"];
          $m2         = $_REQUEST["municipio2"];
          $dp1        = $_REQUEST["depto1"];
          $dp2        = $_REQUEST["depto2"];
          $p1         = $_REQUEST["pais1"];
          $p2         = $_REQUEST["pais2"];
          $t1         = $_REQUEST["tel1"];
          $t2         = $_REQUEST["tel2"];
          $c1         = $_REQUEST["cel1"];
          $f1         = $_REQUEST["fax1"];
          $f2         = $_REQUEST["fax2"];
          $e1         = $_REQUEST["email1"];
          $e2         = $_REQUEST["email2"];
          $area       = $_REQUEST["area"];
          $cargo      = $_REQUEST["cargo"];
          $antiguedad = $_REQUEST["antiguedad"];
          $status     = $_REQUEST["estatus"];
          $emp        = $_REQUEST["empresa"];
      }
      $codigoHTML = '
         //I'll just reduce it to one section of the table, for readability
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                  <table>
                         <tr height=19 >
                                    <td height=19 class=xl65 style="height:14.25pt"></td>
                                    <td class=xl144 style="border-top:none">Municipio</td>
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl95 style="border-left:none">Departamento</td>
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl95 style="border-left:none">Pais</td>
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl95 style="border-left:none">Telefono</td>
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl95 style="border-left:none">Fax</td>
                                    <td colspan=3 class=xl95 style="border-right:1.0pt solid black;border-left:none">Correo Electrónico</td>
                                    <td class=xl65></td>
                                 </tr>
                                <tr height=19 >
                                    <td height=19 class=xl65 style="height:14.25pt"></td>
                                    <td class=xl87 style="border-top:none">'; $codigoHTML .= '' . "$m2" . ''; $codigoHTML .= '</td> 
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl79 style="border-left:none">'; $codigoHTML .= '' . "$dp2" . ''; $codigoHTML .= '</td>
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl79 style="border-left:none">'; $codigoHTML .= '' . "$p2" . ''; $codigoHTML .= '</td>
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl79 style="border-left:none">'; $codigoHTML .= '' . "$t2" . ''; $codigoHTML .= '</td>
                                    <td colspan=2 class=xl79 style="border-left:none">'; $codigoHTML .= '' . "$f1" . ''; $codigoHTML .= '</td>
                                    <td colspan=3 class=xl79 style="border-right:1.0pt solid black;border-left: none">'; $codigoHTML .= '' . "$e2" . ''; $codigoHTML .= '</td>
                                    <td class=xl65></td>
                                </tr>
                  </table>
            </body>
            <html>

                    ';
    $codigoHTML = utf8_decode($codigoHTML);
    $dompdf     = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
    ini_set("memory_limit", "128M");
    $dompdf->set_paper(array(0, 0, 1000, 1087 ));
    $dompdf->render();
    $filename = $a1 . $n . ".pdf";
    $pdf      = $dompdf->output($filename);
    file_put_contents("forms/" . $filename, $pdf);
    $mi_pdf = "forms/" . $filename;
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $mi_pdf . '"');
    readfile($mi_pdf);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you are calling your script twice

Comment: Nothing in your code here indicates a double up on `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: This might be closed as an issue that we cannot reproduce.  I will urge you to shift to prepared statements with placeholders versus escaping.  You can write your conditional on `!$con` instead of calling `errno`.

Comment: I'd say the issue is in your commented bit. ...that you are not saving `$result` in your query condition and you are calling the query function again to access the affected rows or something.  Please extend your code slightly to show your yatta-yatta bit.

Comment: ...and since you are asking for pointers...  if this was my project, because there are so many declarations and `POST` elements, I'd use a hardcoded/master/default array which is used with array_intersect_key to filter out naughty/unwanted elements, then use array_replace to overwrite the default values with the submitted values.  Also I would write the variables that are unassociated with the query after the querying block of code (for readability).

Comment: And it might simplify your code to use pdo prepared statements versus mysqli prepared statements.

Comment: I added the PDF printing procedure so you guys can check if there's something wrong there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a PHP file that contained the HTML page to be generated and included it into this script.

Like this:

```
ob_start();
include 'htmlPage.php';
$codigoHTML = ob_get_clean();

$dompdf     = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(nl2br($codigoHTML));
ini_set("memory_limit", "128M");
$dompdf->set_paper(array(0, 0, 1000, 1087 ));
$dompdf->render();
$filename = $a1 . $n . ".pdf";
$pdf      = $dompdf->output($filename);
file_put_contents("forms/" . $filename, $pdf);
$mi_pdf = "forms/" . $filename;
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $mi_pdf . '"');
readfile($mi_pdf);
```

This solved the double insertion, as I was calling the SQL procedure somewhere in between the long procedure.

Comment: How is this an answer to your question? Did you mean to add this to your question instead of as an answer?

Comment: Check the updated answer, I was in the middle of a power outage when posting, I didn't noticed that the last parragraph was missing when electricity and internet were back in service.